# Why I cannot parse my JSON in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: json, parsing, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to parse this JSON in Xamarin.Forms:

```
[
  {
    "Giorno": "Lunedì",
    "Tipologia": "I Colazione",
    "Alimento": "Fette biscottate",
    "Quantita": 3,
    "UDM": "fette",
    "Note": ""
  }
]
```

I would like to take the elements in the JSON like "Giorno" but I can't, why?
This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using EMN.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EMN
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {

    private ObservableCollection<TestModel> myrootobject;
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

        var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EMN.Dieta.json");

        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)) {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MainPage>>(json);
            //if statement doesn't work because it can't find Giorno
            if (test.Giorno) {

            };

            List<TestModel> mylist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestModel>>(json);
            myrootobject = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(mylist);
            MyListView.ItemsSource = myrootobject; 
        }
    }
}
}
```

TestModel code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;

 namespace EMN.Models {
 public class TestModel {
    public string Giorno { get; set; }
    public string Alimento{ get; set; }
    public string Quantita{ get; set; }
    public string UDM { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

Please, could you help me to parse this JSON?
I've tried also to parse mylist variable but doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using `MainPage` here: `DeserializeObject<List<MainPage>>(json)`

Comment: @Jason I've tried to use the <List<TestModel>> but doesn't work

Comment: well, `MainPage` obviously isn't going to work.  It would help a great deal if you posted the code for `TestModel`

Comment: @Jason yeah, I've posted now, thank you.

Comment: try` DeserializeObject<TestModel>(json)` as your json appears to be a single object

Comment: @Jason now it appears "Giorno", but when I execute it, it gives to me this error: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'EMN.Models.TestModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

Comment: what is the **specific** problem you have when you do `DeserializeObject<List<TestModel>>(json)`?  Does it throw an exception?  And why are you deserializing the same json twice?

Comment: @Jason yes! The error said also :"To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array."

Comment: so you are saying that if you use `List<TestModel>` **OR** just `TestModel` it throws an exception in **BOTH** cases?

Comment: @Jason if I use List<TestModel> i don't have an exception but how can I access to the category of the json there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are deserializing a **LIST** of data

```
List<TestModel> mylist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestModel>>(json);
```

that means you have to specify which element of the list you want in order to access a property

```
// get Giorno property of the FIRST element of the list
var data = mylist[0].Giorno;
```